# MUI DataGrid - onSortModelChange - fires before new sorting has propagated

Tags: material-ui, mui-x-data-grid, mui-x

When I access the `apiRef` onSortModelChange, my function gets called correctly.
However, within that function, if I use something like  `gridSortedRowIdsSelector(apiRef)` I get the order of the rows **BEFORE** the new sorting propagated (i.e., I get the previous / stale / old row order).

What is the proper way to wait for the sorting to propagate?

Right now I'm using a very clunky mechanism that once a sort order has been changed, I start to listen to state changes, and wait for a new order. This seems far less than ideal.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    let rowOrder: TOpportunity['id'][] = [];
    let unsubscribeState = () => {};

    // A function to handle changes to the grid state
    const handleStateChange:GridEventListener<'stateChange'> = () => {
      const newOrder = gridSortedRowIdsSelector(gridApi);
      // If rows are not changing after 1 second, then unsubscribe from state changes
      setTimeout(() => { unsubscribeState(); }, 1000);

      // Check if the new order is different than the previous order
      if (JSON.stringify(newOrder) !== JSON.stringify(rowOrder)) {
        rowOrder = newOrder;
        // Stop listening to state changes
        unsubscribeState?.();
      }
    };

    // handles changes to the sort model
    const handleSortModelChange: GridEventListener<'sortModelChange'> = () => {
      // record the "old" current order to later compare with a "new" order.
      rowOrder = gridSortedRowIdsSelector(gridApi);

      // Subscribes to state changes until a new order is propagated
      unsubscribeState = gridApi.current.subscribeEvent('stateChange', handleStateChange);
    };

    // Subscribes to sort model changes
    const unsubscribeSort = gridApi.current.subscribeEvent('sortModelChange', handleSortModelChange);

    if (rowOrder.length === 0) {
      handleSortModelChange();
    }

    // The `subscribeEvent` method will automatically unsubscribe in the cleanup function of the `useEffect`.
    return () => { unsubscribeState(); unsubscribeSort(); };
  }, [gridApi]);
```

What is the proper way to retrieve the row order within a MUI Data Grid after the grid had been re-sorted?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the correct event (which at the time of writing this answer has not be documented in the official documentation) is `sortedRowsSet`.

See official MUI response [here](https://github.com/mui/mui-x/issues/10201#issuecomment-1707732197)